# "Compiler Error Name argument not found" at title of macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a Compiler error at the first line "Sub New Extract". I am unsure what is wrong. I have downloaded the macro as a xlam and imported it as an add in to a new sheet.
The program takes specific data from the source sheet (where the plugin is added) and copies it to a separate sheet. Below is the main macro with an example of one of the subs im calling (they are all the same just looking for different values).

```
Sub NewExtract()
'Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
'Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MBI DSCR")

Call PasteV
Call PasteCI
Call PasteRI
Call PasteOI
Call PasteTAI
Call PasteRVP
Call PasteRVD
Call PasteCVP
Call PasteCVD
Call PasteCBDP
Call PasteCBDD
Call PasteEGI
Call PasteTE
Call PasteNOI
Call PasteFACR
Call PasteMBIDS
Call PasteECF
Call PasteDSCR
Call PasteName
Call PasteDate
DataToCopy.Copy
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\bbarineau\OneDrive - Merchants Bancorp\Desktop\LBM_DSCT_DataLake.xlsm"
wsDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
              Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

Range("A1").Value = "Date Added"
Range("B1").Value = "Name"
Range("C1").Value = "MBI DSCR Analysis"
Range("D1").Value = "Rental Income"
Range("E1").Value = "Commercial Income"
Range("F1").Value = "Other Income"
Range("G1").Value = "Total All Income"
Range("H1").Value = "Rental Vacancy (%)"
Range("I1").Value = "Rental Vacancy ($)"
Range("J1").Value = "Commercial Vacancy (%)"
Range("K1").Value = "Commercial Vacancy ($)"
Range("L1").Value = "Concessions/Bad Debt(%)"
Range("M1").Value = "Concessions/Bad Debt($)"
Range("N1").Value = "Effective Gross Income"
Range("O1").Value = "Total Expenses"
Range("P1").Value = "NOI"
Range("Q1").Value = "Facility A Contractural Rate"
Range("R1").Value = "MBI Debt Service"
Range("S1").Value = "Excess Cash Flow"
Range("T1").Value = "DSCR"

    Rows.AutoFit
    Columns.AutoFit
    
wSrc.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Here is one of the subs I'm calling
Sub PasteCI()
Dim c As Range, cDest As Range

```
    Set c = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Commercial Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    
    If c Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        Set c = wsSrc.Range("B40:G40")
        DataToCopy = Union(c, DataToCopy)
    Else
       DataToCopy = Union(DataToCopy, c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6))
    End If
End Sub
```

Defined Variables above the main macro

```
Property Get wsSrc() As Worksheet
     Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MBI DSCR")
End Property
Property Get wSrc() As Workbook
Set wSrc = ActiveWorkbook
End Property
Property Get col() As Long
    col = wsSrc.Columns.Find(What:="MBI", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Property
Property Get col2() As Long
    col2 = wSrc.Sheets("Inputs").Columns.Find(What:="Deal Team", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Property

Property Get wsDest() As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("LBM_DSCT_DataLake.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Property
```

Note that the variables are defined above in lines before Sub NewExtract()
If anyone can see the issue with this, or any others with my code,  please let me know!

Comment: You're using the `Worksheet.PasteSpecial` method but supplying the arguments for the `Range.PasteSpecial` method.

Comment: ok so I just changed it and am now getting an invalid call or argument error at the  `DataToCopy = Union(c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6), DataToCopy)` line and I'm unsure why. I want to copy certain ranges then paste and I feel ike this is how to do it but whats going wrong. Its at the first occurence, so is the error coming from DataToCopy being nothing

Comment: You need `Set` because it's an object variable.